# Sum for values in my array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below, and I want to do the total of values in a spefic manner where all values of val1_(.*) {regular expressions}, and similarly other values.
I have only specific vals like val1, val2, and val3.

My array is like:

```
$stats = Array
(
    [ADDED_NEW_2012_06_12] => 16
    [ADDED_OLD_2012_06_12] => 10
    [ADD_LATER_2012_06_12] => 12
    [ADDED_NEW_2012_06_11] => 16
    [ADDED_OLD_2012_06_11] => 10
    [ADD_LATER_2012_06_11] => 12
)
```

Can you please tell me how can i obtain my result. I don't know how to add such values using regex in php. Please help.

Comment: what is name of your array object ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need a regular expression if you can identify the values by the first part of the key.

Iterate over the array and create a new array with one element for each `valX`:

```
$totals = array();

// iterate over the array
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $k = substr($key, 0, strpos($key, '_')); // get the first part (i.e. `valX`)
    if(!isset($totals[$k])) { // if $totals['valX'] does not exist, initialize
        $totals[$k] = 0;
    }
    $totals[$k] += $value; // sum
}
```

**Reference:** [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: actually val1 and val2 were just the example, my actual array keys are ADDED_NEW_2012_06_12, ADDED_NEW_2012_06_11 etc. Can I modify your code for my situation?

Comment: If you don't modify it, you cannot apply it to your situation, or can you? ;) Of course! Answers normally don't and should not give copy and paste solutions anyway, just a generell idea.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
$array = array (
  'val1_2012_06_12' => 16,
  'val2_2012_06_12' => 10,
  'val3_2012_06_12' => 12,
  'val1_2012_06_11' => 16,
  'val2_2012_06_11' => 10,
  'val3_2012_06_11' => 12,
);

$sums = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $regex = '~(?P<prefix>val\d+)_\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}~';

  if (preg_match($regex, $key, $matches)) {
    $sums[$matches['prefix']] += $value;
  }
}
```

It will produce something like this, it will group sums by prefixes:

```
Array
(
    [val1] => 32
    [val2] => 20
    [val3] => 24
)
```

Comment: actually val1 and val2 were just the example, my actual array keys are ADDED_NEW_2012_06_12, ADDED_NEW_2012_06_11 etc. Can I modify your code for my situation?

Comment: @Mohan Sinfh of course you can modify code you just need to modify "val\d+" part with appropriate pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: updated to the refined question**

You can match the key against a code, and create a sum from there like this with a simple foreach loop.

```
$array = array(
    'ADDED_NEW_2012_06_12' => 16,
    'ADDED_OLD_2012_06_12' => 10,
    'ADD_LATER_2012_06_12' => 12,
    'ADDED_NEW_2012_06_11' => 16,
    'ADDED_OLD_2012_06_11' => 10,
    'ADD_LATER_2012_06_11' => 12,
);


$sumarray = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
   $matches = array();
   preg_match("/^(\w+?_\w+?)_/i", $key, $matches);
   $key = $matches[1];
   if (!isset($sumarray[$key]))
   {
      $sumarray[$key] = $value;
   } else {
      $sumarray[$key] = $sumarray[$key] + $value;
   }
}

print_r($sumarray);
```

Comment: actually val1 and val2 were just the example, my actual array keys are ADDED_NEW_2012_06_12, ADDED_NEW_2012_06_11 etc. Can I modify your code for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

if you have just this tree type of value in array so you can use this:

```
$stats = Array(
    'ADDED_NEW_2012_06_12' => 16,
    'ADDED_OLD_2012_06_12' => 10,
    'ADD_LATER_2012_06_12' => 12,
    'ADDED_NEW_2012_06_11' => 16,
    'ADDED_OLD_2012_06_11' => 10,
    'ADD_LATER_2012_06_11' => 12
);  

foreach($stats as $key => $value)
{
 $substring=substr($key, 0 , 9);
  if($substring=='ADDED_NEW')
    @$ADDED_NEW += $value;
  elseif($substring=='ADDED_OLD')
    @$ADDED_OLD += $value;
  else
    @$ADD_LATER += $value;
}
echo 'ADDED_NEW : ' . $ADDED_NEW .'<br>ADDED_OLD : ' . $ADDED_OLD .'<br>ADD_LATER : ' . $ADD_LATER ;
```

Output :

```
ADDED_NEW : 32
ADDED_OLD : 20
ADD_LATER : 24
```

Comment: actually val1 and val2 were just the example, my actual array keys are ADDED_NEW_2012_06_12, ADDED_NEW_2012_06_11 etc. Can I modify your code for my situation?

Comment: i Updated code . if you have more than tree type of ADD (value) in array you can use switch (case :) inside foreach  .

Answer (score -4):

$sum = 0;
Foreach($object as $key=>$value){
$sum += $value;
}

Comment: Woops. I'm out. Can't do regex on iPhone!